# Nav Links Stack When Zoom Out

Tags: html, css, navigation

So I'm building a website in html and css. I have made a navigation bar with the links, but when I zoom out, the links go underneath one another instead of inline. If someone can give me some pointers, that'd be great. Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
<div class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png"></div>
<div class="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="">PRODUCTS</a></li>
<li><a href="">SHOPS</a></li>
<li><a href="">FAQ</a></li>
<li><a href="">ABOUT US</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="main">

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
     body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #1b1b1b url('../img/bg.jpg') no-repeat fixed top center;
}

.logo {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 524px;
}

.wrap {
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
}

.nav {
    height: 37px;
    background-color: rgba(26,26,26,0.8);
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 38px;
}

ul li {
    display: inline;
    color: #828282;
    padding: 2px 40px;
    background: #595959;
    border:1px solid #828282;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: arial;
}

ul li a:hover {

}

.main {
    min-height: 300px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgba(26,26,26,0.8);
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: just an advice, an jsfiddle link would be nice

Comment: You need to look into "responsive design". However, most browsers by default don't zoom text only, so you won't normally see what you are describing.

Comment: You should change the display property of 'ul li' to 'display: inline-block' and reduce its value of margin-left and margin-right.

Answer (score 0):

"the links go underneath one another instead of inline"

To fix this, you will want to add the `float: left;` property to your li like so:

```
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    color: #828282;
    padding: 2px 40px;
    background: #595959;
    border:1px solid #828282;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: The last nav link goes underneath the rest still when I zoom in. I want to keep the ul centered within my nav class, therefore i cant float left

Comment: @Donavon I created a fiddle but I can't repro your bug:  http://jsfiddle.net/cm16upcq/ It seems to work fine in Chrome

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/fuVM3Bg.png when i zoom all the way out, that's what the links do

Comment: @Donavon I see what you mean; at 25% zoom.  Unfortunately; I am not sure how to solve that.  Guess is that chrome enlarges the font at lower zooms.